# req.logIn is not being automatically invoked by passport.authenticate

Tags: node.js, authentication, serialization, passport.js, express-session

I've been upgrading the passport version from 0.4.1 to 0.6.0 and faced the issue with the session being regenerated on log in. In my application the session does more than just keep the user logged in, so I need the session persist. I've read the threads on how to fix that by adding the keepSessionInfo: true flag. However, if I add it to the req.logIn function it does nothing. But according to the [official documentation](https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/login/) req.logIn should be automatically invoked anyways, so when I comment it out the session is persistent. However, it creates another issue - the user doesn't get serialized/deserialized anymore and it looks like the req.logIn is not being invoked.

I can technically manually perform serialization, but would like to keep the original flow. What am I doing wrong here?

```
// Authentication
app.post('/api/user/log-in', verifySession, (req, res, next) => {
  // Empty/data checks
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    res.json({error: 'All fields must be filled out.'})
  } else if (!Util.validateAlphaNumeric(req.body.username)) {
    res.json({
      error: 'Username or password is wrong.',
    })
  } else if (!Util.validatePassword(req.body.password)) {
    res.json({
      error: 'Username or password is wrong.',
    })
  } else if (!req.body.password || !req.body.username) {
    res.json({error: 'All fields must be filled out.'})
  } else {
    passport.authenticate(
      'local',
      {keepSessionInfo: true},
      (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err
        }
        if (!user) {
          res.json({error: 'Username or password is wrong.'})
        } else {
          // req.logIn(user, {keepSessionInfo: true}, (err) => {
          //   if (err) {
          //     throw err
          //   }

          // Manually perform serialization since req.logIn is not being invoked
          req.session.passport = {
          user: user.user_id,
          }

          // Set logged_in flag in session store
          // All the authorized routes on the UI rely on this flag
          req.session.logged_in = true

          // Put roles in the array
          const userRoles = []
          user.Roles.forEach((element) => userRoles.push(element.role_name))

          res.json({
            id: user.user_id,
            username: user.username,
            roles: userRoles,
            logged_in: true,
          })
          // })
        }
      },
    )(req, res, next)
  }
})
```